# QT MYSQL drive build, undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version@0'

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5, qmake

I am trying to build the QMYSQL drive, I followed Document (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows)

it recommond me runned the code :

```
cd %QTDIR%\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers
qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySQL/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MYSQL/MySQL Server <version>/lib/opt"
nmake sub-mysql
```

There is no "Libs & Include Files" Module in mysql "Custom Install", so I select the folder from the sql serves.

I run the code on cmd:

```
cd C:\Qt\5.12.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers
qmake --  "MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySql/MySQL Server 8.0/include" "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MySql/MySQL Server 8.0/lib"
```

the result is :

```
info: creating stash file C:\Qt\5.12.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\.qmake.stash

Running configuration tests...
Checking for DB2 (IBM)... no
Checking for InterBase... no
Checking for MySQL... no
Checking for OCI (Oracle)... no
Checking for ODBC... yes
Checking for PostgreSQL... no
Checking for SQLite (version 2)... no
Checking for TDS (Sybase)... no
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'mingw32-make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'mingw32-make install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\Qt\5.12.6\mingw73_32'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

it seems like does not detected mysql. what should I do to build the mysql drive.

I checked the the config log for qmake:

```
    Trying source 5 (type inline) of library mysql ...
+ cd /d C:\Qt\5.12.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\config.tests\mysql && C:\Qt\5.12.6\mingw73_32\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\openssl\\lib C:\\Utils\\my_sql\\mysql-5.6.11-win32\\lib C:\\Utils\\postgresql\\pgsql\\lib" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\openssl\\include C:\\Utils\\my_sql\\mysql-5.6.11-win32\\include C:\\Utils\\postgresql\\pgsql\\include" "QMAKE_USE += mysql" "QMAKE_LIBS_MYSQL = \"C:/MySql/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/libmysql.lib\"" "QMAKE_INCDIR_MYSQL = \"C:/MySql/MySQL Server 8.0/include\"" C:/Qt/5.12.6/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/config.tests/mysql
> Info: creating stash file C:\Qt\5.12.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\config.tests\.qmake.stash
+ cd /d C:\Qt\5.12.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\config.tests\mysql && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -w -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -I. -IC:\openssl\include -IC:\Utils\my_sql\mysql-5.6.11-win32\include -IC:\Utils\postgresql\pgsql\include -I"C:\MySql\MySQL Server 8.0\include" -IC:\Qt\5.12.6\mingw73_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o main.o main.cpp
> g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o mysql.exe main.o  -LC:\openssl\lib -LC:\Utils\my_sql\mysql-5.6.11-win32\lib -LC:\Utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib "C:\MySql\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib"   
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version@0'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:66: mysql.exe] Error 1
```

I think here is my problem,

> undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version@0'

but I do not know how to solve it.I am sure there is a "mysql.h" file in "include" folder with a method

> unsigned long STDCALL mysql_get_client_version(void);

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I solved It the qmake is 86X, and server is 64X. change a 64X qmake worked

this doc is better then old one.

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.14/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows